# Arrow keys not working in Solaris 10 Console Installation

Tags: installation, solaris, console

I am trying to install Solaris 10 and facing a  problem on selecting options. In network interface configuration I need to specify the IP Address of the router. The installation says as below.

```
To make a selection, use the arrow keys to select your choice and press
Return to mark it [X].
  Default Route for bge0
  [X] Detect one upon reboot
  [ ] Specify one
  [ ] None
```

But when I press the Arrow keys the cursor does not move up or down. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type in the first letter(s) of the option and the cursor will move there. Then hit space to select that option.

Another solution is to choose the correct terminal type right at the start of the installation process. I normally choose xterm, but if you're using the serial port directly you may have more luck with vt100.